# how to restrict active admin to admin users only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a user model with rolify gem. In my app I am using active_admin as admin interface.
Have can I restrict active_admin to admin users only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your rolify role check in the same place as mentioned in the [Active Admin documentation's example for getting access to the current user](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#getting_access_to_the_current_user):

```
class OnlyAdmins < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    # Do rolify check here
    user.has_role? :admin
  end
end
```

Comment: Finally I opted for cancan authorization.